# Rails Multiple Access Levels

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new to ruby on rails, and I'm attempting to code a website that has four different user access levels (delegate, adviser, chair, admin). For each one, I want to create a different set of views upon login, so that they have different functionality. What would be the best way to validate the User login and redirect to the controllers for each access level?

Answer (score 1):

Probably you want something called Rolebased authentication.
The easiest one, is to add string field "role" to User model.

Regarding redirection upon login it depends on what authentication system you use.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def after_sign_in_path
    "/#{current_user.role}"
  end
end
```

One of the easiest way is to use [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) and its [after sign in callback](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-in)

But also, probably, consider not creating different controllers, but use different [layouts](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html), like:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  layout :choose_layout

  private

  def choose_layout
    current_user.role.presence || 'application'
  end
end
```

Another way, is to use [routing constraints](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#http-verb-constraints)

But, of course, it depends on your app logic.

It seems the best to create different [namespaces](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing) for each role if you want completely different views:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  namespace :admin do
  end

  namespace :advisor do
  end
  ...
end
```

Then you just create directories under views called, accordingly: admin, delegate, advisor, chair

Answer (score 0):

I recommend the use of CanCanCan gem https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan. You can set permissions for each role easily and with relatively low effort.